# AjaxFileUpload file not inheriting folder permissions

Tags: asp.net, iis, file-upload, file-permissions, asyncfileupload

I am successfully uploading a file using the AjaxFileUpload control from the AjaxToolkit. I had to give `IUSR` write permissions to the folder but after that there was no problem.

However, the files which are uploaded are not inheriting the permissions set on the folder, so they do not have `IUSR` listed. On my local machine this isn't much of a problem, but on the server it means a 401 is returned as IUSR read permission is needed on the file in order to read it.

From what I can see, the folder is set to apply permissions to files inside, which leads me to believe it is something to do with the way the file is saved to the folder. Does anyone know anything more about this?

**UPDATE**

OK so I found some more information about the problem. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/viag/archive/2006/10/25/how-to-change-the-default-tempfile-upload-location-for-the-asp-net-2-0-fileupload-control.aspx) suggested that before the file is saved to the specified location, it is first held in a temporary location. The workaround they suggest (changing the temporary location to somewhere known and setting permissions on it) does not appear to work for the AjaxFileUpload. The rest of the project temporary files appear in there, but using the Process Monitor I can see that my temporary location is somewhere else entirely for the uploaded images:

[image: C:\Windows\Temp_AjaxFileUpload]

If I set the permissions on this folder for `IUSR` then my problem is fixed. So the next question, will this location always exist? My guess is no. If so, how can I change it?

**UPDATE 2**

OK so I found there was some static methods on the control which are set to build the temporary directory:

```
public static string BuildTempFolder(string fileId)
{
  return Path.Combine(AjaxFileUpload.BuildRootTempFolder(), fileId);
}

public static string BuildRootTempFolder()
{
  string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "_AjaxFileUpload");
  if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
  return path;
}
```

One of the key lines is probably this: `string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "_AjaxFileUpload");` which seems to match with what I'd found in my process monitor. It seems that without rebuilding the project I'm stuck with their default settings, so I may look elsewhere for a different tool.

Answer (score 2):

thanx chris

I had the same problem and I am not going to drop ajaxfileUpload control now , so I found workaround

1- download the source code from [codeplex](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/116091)

2- open "source code directory"\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\AjaxFileUpload\AjaxFileUpload.cs and add static property name it ***UploadRootPath***

```
public static string UploadRootPath
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

3- modify ***BuildRootTempFolder*** function :

```
public static string BuildRootTempFolder()
    {
        var rootTempFolder = "";
        if (UploadRootPath == "")
        {
            rootTempFolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), TemporaryUploadFolderName);
        }
        else {
            rootTempFolder = Path.Combine(UploadRootPath, TemporaryUploadFolderName);
        }

        if (!Directory.Exists(rootTempFolder))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(rootTempFolder);

        return rootTempFolder;
    }
```

4- Build solution and use the new ***AjaxControlToolkit.dll*** in your project.

5- in your project set the directory where you want the temporary files to be saved in .

```
AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload.UploadRootPath = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/Temp/");
```

I wish ***DevExpress*** guys do it in their next update , and I am sure they will do it in a decent way